# Downgrade Karate versions

Tags: dependencies, cucumber, pom.xml, karate, automation-testing

I am currently using **Karate core version 1.2.0** ,**Karate apache version 0.9.6** and **Karate junit version 1.1.0** if I downgrade from this versions will there be any major functionality impact ? Can you give me any suggestions for these **three** dependencies ?

| Dependencies | Versions |
| --- | --- |
| Karate core | 1.2.0 |
| Karate apache | 0.9.6 |
| Karate junit | 1.1.0 |

**Dependencies**

1.*Karate core*

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
<artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
<version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

2.*Karate Apache*

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
<artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
<version>0.9.6</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

3.*Karate Junit5*

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
<artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never supposed to combine Karate versions. So please assume that what you are asking for is not supported.

Comment: No i am not asking to combine versions , if i use the lower versions of these three dependencies which i mentioned above will there be any major impact.

Comment: @Subhashini let me add that lower versions are definitely not something that the open-source project will ever support. but since it is open-source, you are welcome to contribute code or use it any way you want. I personally cannot understand what you mean by impact, and my answer is "I don't know"

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend downgrading karate version , there are quite a few changes in 1.2.0 from earlier versions also you should use same latest version  for karate-junit5 and karate-core dependencies